# Save String grid with header and setup col width

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I would like to save all the String grid data to .xls file. I found a solution which seems to be ok, but the first fixed rows (the column headers) are missing. How can I save it? The other thing is it is possible to set the col width equal to my String grid?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
procedure SaveToXls;
var
  lXls, lWb, lRange: OLEVariant;
  lArrData: Variant;
  lRowCount, lColCount, I, J: Integer;
begin
  lRowCount := stGrid.RowCount;
  lColCount := stGrid.ColCount;
  lArrData := VarArrayCreate([1, lRowCount, 1, lColCount], varVariant);

  for i := 1 to lRowCount do
    for j := 1 to lColCount do
      lArrData[i, j] := stGrid.Cells[j-1, i-1];

  lXls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  lWb := lXls.Workbooks.Add;
  lRange := lWb.WorkSheets[1].Range[lWb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[1, 1],
  lWb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[lRowCount, lColCount]];

  lRange.Value := lArrData;
  lXls.Visible := True;
end;
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Just, the code you've posted is malformed, `lWb.WorkSheets[1].lRange` is incorrect (`lRange` is some variable declared in your code). So I assume you haven't posted real code here.

Comment: There is a typo in your code, `Worksheet` object does not have `lRange` property. Other than that, this code should work correctly, at least it did in my  test example.

Comment: Sorry for that, i typed it... fixed for range prop

Comment: Yes, works perfectly for me too. There must be some other problem in your real code.

Answer (score 1):

For me the code works. To set the column width, assuming a variable font, the following works (Excel widths are multiples of the width of character '0' for variable fonts):

```
function TForm1.CalcWidth: integer;
var
  iWidthZero : integer;
begin
  // assume variable font
  iWidthZero := stGrid.Canvas.TextWidth('0');
  Result := (stGrid.DefaultColWidth + iWidthZero - 1) div iWidthZero;
end;
```

and adding to your displayed function

```
  lRange.ColumnWidth := CalcWidth;
```

at the bottom.

Obviously a similar method would work column by column if you wanted, but you would have to set your ranges accordingly.